# How to show percentage of upload in progress bar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, paperclip

I'm using Paperclip for image upload. I need to show percentage of size uploading to server in the percentage bar. Can anyone please offer me a solution that could be compatible with paperclip. (If Uploadify would be the solution, can you please suggest a tutorial for how to use it along with paperclip)

P.S. Sorry, Of course, there are many similar questions around forums, but I couldn't find an appropriate solution for my need and more'er, most of them leads to an outdated solution or landing in a "not found". So, any help would matter a lot. TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this https://github.com/hayageek/jquery-upload-file

And also i have added sample application for your requirement. You can get it from https://github.com/prakash-subramani/paperclip-file-upload-progress

Answer (score 0):

If you're set on using paperclip, this will work: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Consider using something like filepicker...it will do this for you out of the box: https://github.com/Ink/filepicker-rails

Comment: Can I pull "progress bar" alone from jQuery-File-Upload without disturbing or making changes to my Paperclip upload?!